# Having trouble accessing JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file which contains football teams from every country.
Example:

```
var FootballTeams = {  
   "Spain":[  
      "RealMadrid",
      "Barcelona",
      "Valencia"
   ],
   "England":[  
      "ManchesterCity",
      "Arsenal",
      "Chelsea",
      "ManchesterUnited",
      "Liverpool"
   ]
};
```

My program receives an user input with the country name, and I randomly give them a team from the selected country, as follows:

```
var SelectedCountry= $('#UserInput').val(); // "Spain" or "England"
alert(FootballTeams.SelectedCountry[Math.floor(Math.random()*FootballTeams.countryf.length)]);
```

It doesn't seem to be working, though I can access the array if I insert the string directly:

```
alert(FootballTeams."Spain"[Math.floor(Math.random()*FootballTeams.countryf.length)]);
```

How is it possible to make the first option work ?

Comment: Use Code formatting, not Quotation, for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud try like this when accessing a `key` of object using variable.

```
alert(FootballTeams[SelectedCountry][Math.floor(Math.random()*FootballTeams.countryf.length)]);
```